# Add custom text to event in Day view - FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

How to add custom text in a fullcalendar event day view. I have this requirement to add a tagging in the event. Please refer to image attached.

[image: FullCalendar reference]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add something to an event, look at thee [eventRender](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/eventRender) - you can modify the HTML of the event an way you want, and you have access to all the event's properties as a data source.

e.g.

```
eventRender: function(info)
{
  info.el.innerHTML += info.event.extendedProps.description;
}
```

N.B. This specific example relies on you having an extra property called "description" in the event data you pass to the calendar - demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/qBKvqom . But of course you can also simply manipulate the existing content, or display something from another standard property too. The world's your oyster.